# Python string not clearing correctly in loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I am wring a script where I need to go through a csv file and find am looking for the first time that specific user logged in, and the last time they logged out. I have loops set up that are working great but when I clear the lists with the time string of their login/logout, I get an Index out of range error. Can anyone spot anything incorrect with this?

```
    #this gets the earliest login time for each agent (but it assumes all dates to be the same!)
with open(inputFile, 'r') as dailyAgentLog:
    csv_read = csv.DictReader(dailyAgentLog)
    firstLoginTime = []
    lastLogoutTime = []
    outputLine = []
    while x < len(agentName):
        for row in csv_read:
            if row["Agent"] == agentName[x]:
                firstLoginTime.append(datetime.strptime(row["Login Time"], '%I:%M:%S %p'))
                lastLogoutTime.append(datetime.strptime(row["Logout Time"], '%I:%M:%S %p'))
        firstLoginTime.sort()
        lastLogoutTime.sort()
        outputLine = [agentName[x], agentLogin[x], agentExtension[x], row["Login Date"], firstLoginTime[0], row["Logout Date"], lastLogoutTime[-1]]
        print(f'Agent {agentName[x]} first login was {firstLoginTime[0]} and last logout {lastLogoutTime[-1]}.')
        fileLines.append(outputLine)

        x += 1

        firstLoginTime.clear() #this should be emptying/clearing the list at the end of every iteration
        lastLogoutTime.clear()
```

Comment: Could you share your input, expected output, and the full error? See [mcve].

Comment: You can only iterate through `csv_read` once. When you get to the end of the file, there won't be anything left to read, unless you do `dailyAgentLog.seek(0)`

Comment: Not related to the problem but Pythonistas prefer `snake_case_variables` instead of `camelCaseVariables`. Not a requirement but your code will look better if you follow [PEP8, Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on the 2nd and following iterations, the `for row in csv_read:` loop doesn't execute, because there's nothing left to read. So you never fill in the `firstLoginTime` and `lastLoginTime` lists on subsequent iterations, and indexing them fails.

If the file isn't too large, you can read it into a list before iterating:

```
csv_read = list(csv.DictReader(dailyAgentLog))
```

If it's too big to hold in memory, put

```
dailyAgentLog.seek(0)
```

at the end of the loop body.

Also, instead of sorting the lists, you can use `min()` and `max()`:

```
firstLogin = min(firstLoginTime)
lastLogin = max(lastLoginTime)
```

And I suggest you use

```
for x in range(len(agentName)):
```

rather than `while` and increment.

Comment: Thanks a ton I appreciate it. It has been a while since I have gotten my feet wet in programming so I am trying to knock off the rust. I appreciate your tips and time to help me out!